# Register .es domain name

Tags: domain-registration, international

I wish to register an .es domain name, but I live in the UK.

Registration seems to require an ID number, but it isn't clear if this is only for Spanish residents.

Am I OK to supply my passport/drivers licence number as a UK resident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be fine. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.es):

> Second-level registrations have had some limitations including requiring registrants to have a connection with Spain, but these restrictions were lifted in a multi-stage process completed by the end of 2005, at which point registrations at the second level of .es were open to anybody worldwide.

Comment: Presumably this answer applies to individuals and businesses? I'm an individual that plans on making it a business some day.

Comment: It does. They accept all registrations.